# Magento 2 created robots.txt/sitemap.xml in `http/` but not `pub/`

Tags: magento-2.1, robots.txt

I have created a `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml` files using Magento UI but when trying to access *www.mydomain.com/robots.txt* or *www.mydomain.com/sitemap.xml* it gives me `404 not found`.

I found that `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml` file are created in `mydomain/http/`, however, the `pub` directory is set to be my root so moving the file to the `pub` fixes the issue.

Why Magento created the files in this location?
If I want to make changes to the `robots.txt` file, I can't use the native Magento feature?
What is the best solution to this?

I am using **NginX** and added this to my configuration file which "solves" the issue, however I am not sure if this is the best solution:

```
# robots
location = /robots.txt {
    alias /var/www/example.com/html/robots.txt;
}

# sitemap
location = /sitemap.xml {
    alias /var/www/example.com/html/sitemap.xml;
}
```

I am using Magento 2.1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in Magento 2.2.1, see https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/9094.

Comment: Great! Thanks for getting back :) I hope someone else find this useful :)

Comment: 2.2.9 and I don't see any change in magento's behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I am running 2.3.3 and it is not fixed.

The workaround was to add `/pub/sitemap.xml` in the field and then generate.

Magento backend will show the link with the `/pub/` like this: `http://example.com/pub/sitemap.xml`, which will show 404 since the `vhost` is pointed to `pub`.

However, the file is generated inside the `pub` folder. That means it can be accessed as `http://example.com/sitemap.xml`.

Hope this helps someone.

Hope this helps.